# How to retrieve value of filed on mongodb

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I have a collect product like below

```
{id: "A-2019-01-01",
  date: 2019-01-01,
  name; "product A"
},
{ id: "B-2019-02-01",
  date: null,
  name; "product B"
}
```

If the date is null, I must parse Id filed to get Date.

Here is my condition:

```
ConditionalOperators.Switch.CaseOperator cond1 = ConditionalOperators.Switch.CaseOperator.
    when(BooleanOperators.And.and(ComparisonOperators.valueOf("date").lessThanEqualToValue(0)))
            .then("$id");
```

and another function to parse date

```
public static LocalDateTime getDateFromId(String id) {
    String startDate = StringUtils.substringAfter(id, "-");
    final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
    LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDate.parse(startDate, formatter).atStartOfDay();
    return dateTime;
}
```

Do we get the value of field "id" and call getDateFromId() function on ConditionalOperators.

```
 .and(ConditionalOperators.switchCases(cond1).defaultTo(0)).as("date")
```